# <html:multibox> equivalent in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, struts-1, struts2-jquery

Below is the html tag multibox which i want to migrate it to struts 2

```jsp
<html:multibox name="unitForm" property="eservices">
    <bean:write name="service"/>
</html:multibox>
```

as it is checkbox so thought of using simple checkbox which is in the iterator so i used below code

```jsp
<s:checkbox theme="simple" name="unitForm.eservices"></s:checkbox>
```

in action

```java
String[] toArray = new String[selectedadminVOs.size()];
unitForm.setEservices(selectedadminVOs.toArray(toArray));
```

stuck here,without or minimal changes in action code how can i migrate it to struts2

Comment: There is a `<s:checkboxlist>` tag:  http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/checkboxlist.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM: yes i even i tried that but it was not showing preselected checkbox

Comment: Ask that question instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `<html:multibox>` equivalent in Struts 2 is

```xml
<s:iterator var="row" value="%{unitForm.eservices}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="unitForm.checked" 
        value="${row.service}" ${unitForm.checked.contains(row.service)?'checked="checked"':''}/>    
</s:iterator>
```

or you can use `s:property` tag

```xml
<s:iterator var="row" value="%{unitForm.eservices}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="unitForm.checked" 
        value="${row.service}" <s:property value="%{unitForm.checked.contains(#row.service)?'checked="checked"':''}"/>/>    
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have this error: Encountered "(". Expected one of : "}", ".", "[", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", ">=", "ge", "<=", "le", "==", "eq", "!=", "ne", "&&", "and", "||", "or", "*", "+", "-", "?", "/", "div", "%", "mod", 
     [java]                 value="${row.service}" ${selectedfiles.contains(row.service)?'checked="checked"':''}/> where selectedfiles is name of input

Comment: Hi Roman (this is not a rhetorical question), but wondering why you havn't  mentioned an s:checkboxlist... is it not appropriate in this case?

Comment: @johnm it could be appropriate if you find a solution to the problem like I did in this answer before.