# How to make JSP input checkbox checked by default?

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, struts-tags

I have a checkbox in JSP, which consists of a `HashMap<String, String>`, e.g.,

```
"1", "Name"
"2", "Age"
"3", "Gender"
```

Now I want the first entry be checked by default, how should I write the `if test` code? The current code is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="params" value="<s:property value="#param.key"/>"
<s:iterator value="params" var="app">
<s:if test="???">
onclick="return false"
checked="checked"
</s:if>
</s:iterator>/>
&emsp;<s:property value="#param.value"/>
```

Comment: How a single checkbox can contain a whole hashmap?

Comment: There is a <s:iterator value="paramMap" var="param"> on the top.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re trying to do here. You should include the complete code and data.

Comment: The iterator has nothing with a single checkbox. If you need multiple checkboxes then you can try a `<s:checkboxlist>` tag, or you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654697/573032) solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<s:iterator>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html) has a `status` attribute were you can use a variable

```
<s:iterator value="params" var="app" status="paramStatus">
<s:if test="#paramSatus.index == 0">
onclick="return false"
checked="checked"
</s:if>
</s:iterator>
```